# NSUserDefaults does not save

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsuserdefaults, saving-data

I use the NSUserDefaults method to save data. I save an int and an NSMutableArray.

The int gets saved properly when the app terminates, enters the background, or switches to another view. The array saves when the app enters the background and when it switches to another view, but doesn't save every time I exit the simulator and come back in, even though I use the exact same code for the int and the NSMutableArray.

Here's my code for defining the NSMutableArray:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([prefs objectForKey:@"array"] != nil) {
array = [prefs objectForKey:@"array"];
}
```

And then for editing and saving it:

```
[array addObject:anObject];
[prefs setObject:array forKey:@"array"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

The int has the exact same code except for the changes between array and int parts.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
I've checked many related questions but none of them solved my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

"Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value."

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You're assigning a pointer to an *immutable NSArray* returned by `[NSUserDefaults objectForKey:...]` to a pointer to an *NSMutableArray*. You then use `addObject:` on the NSArray (which has no effect) and save the unchanged *NSArray*.

(You may also have a memory leak since you're allocing the NSImmutableArray every time.)

Comment: but then, how should I save it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

This will definitely save & retrieve your NSUserDefault values.

```
- (void) retrieveMyState
 {
//Retrieving
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSInteger *yourIntValue = [prefs integerForKey:@"yourIntValue"];

    // convert your NSData to array, and then use it as required.   

NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [prefs objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
{
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

}


 -(void) saveMyState 
{
//saving
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setInteger:yourIntValue forKey:@"yourIntValue"];

    // convert your array to NSData & then save it as object.

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourArray];
[prefs setObject:data forKey:@"yourArray"];

[prefs synchronize];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I tried it and it still doesn't solve my problem!

Comment: By looking at your code, I don’t think you are using NSData to store Array. If you are doing so, please paste some code of conversion of NSData to Array & vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Write :

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];
if ([prefs objectForKey:@"array"] != nil)
    [array setArray:[prefs objectForKey:@"array"]];
```

when defining the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save an "int".  It's not a NSObject.

But you can embed a NSNumber into your array and that will save.

Try [`[NSNumber numberWithInt: ]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithInt%3a) (I linked to the Apple documentation).

Hopefully this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's actually the int that saves correctly and the array that doesn't :(

Comment: What are the contents of your array?  NSStrings or NSData or custom Objective C objects?

Comment: It's made up of NSStrings only